# query.list() in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

`query.list` returns list of object `arrays`.

Now there is already written code which I can't change

```
List<MYPOJO> abc = query.list();
```

The issue is while parsing, as when I parse the above list

```
for(MYPOJO x : abc) <-- this gives type cast error 
                       (runtime error cannot typecast object array to MYPOJO)
```

and `for (Object[] : abc)` gives me `compile time error`.

I cannot change `List<MYPOJO> abc = query.list();` code as this is in another project. Is there a way to `iterate` the above list?

Comment: what does `query.list();` returns  ?

Comment: @Ravi i think query.list() return is stored in a raw List as explained before edition. `List abc = query.list();` otherwise there would not have problem

Comment: are you sure the assignment to abc does not give any problem? if the list() method returns Object[] the compiler is bound to complain...

Comment: @ManricoCorazzi you're right if query.list() return Object[] so compiler should complain when assigning list() return to abc...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
for (Object o : abc)
{
   Object[] array = (Object[])o;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think he want to cast Object o into MYPOJO in the loop: `MYPOJO pojo = (MYPOJO) o;`